# Is there something special about the .Spotlight directories/data?

Tags: finder, spotlight

I am nearly out of disk space and trying to remove old/unused files. I ran 
     du -k -d 2

in my home directory to attempt to identify candidates and found the following:

```
4   ./.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1
3297484 ./.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2
3297492 ./.Spotlight-V100
```

That's 6.6GB between them. I'd like to see if the `V1` were still in use or just old.  But that directory is not viewable from `iTerm` ?

```
$ls -lrta $HOME/.Spot\*
ls: /Users/myuser/.Spot*: No such file or directory
```

That directory also does not show up in `Finder` even though I have enabled "Show hidden files".

So what is going on with those directories - or are they truly inaccessible?

Comment: @fd0  Please make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Spotlight-V100` directories are found in the root of each mounted volume. Try-

```
ls -lOde@ /Volumes/*/.Spot*
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may delete those directories.

These directories house files that are indexes to allow searching your drive with Spotlight. (see the magnifying glass on the menubar of your Mac.)  Deleting those indexes will force spotlight to re-index your drive (which is perfectly natural) and it will make a new index, hopefully something small and tidy.  I've no idea why your index is so large and would hope that the new index will take up MBs rather than GBs.

Comment: This is helpful : the comment from @fd0 actually shows how to find it in `iTerm`